# ConstraintLayout - Dynamically set constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintset

Basic example of multiple `ConstrainLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/constLayout_root"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constLayout_A"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#ff0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constLayout_B"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#f0f"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constLayout_C"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#0f0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constLayout_A"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`constLayout_B` overlays `constLayout_A`, and `constLayout_C` is now displayed below `constLayout_A`.

Now I need to programatically change constraints and display `constLayout_C` below `constLayout_B` (and hide `constLayout_A`).

I have tried to chain them together in this way:

```
final ConstraintSet cs_C = new ConstraintSet();
cs_C.connect(constLayout_C.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constLayout_B.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
cs_C.connect(constLayout_C.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
cs_C.connect(constLayout_C.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
cs_C.connect(constLayout_C.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);
cs_C.applyTo(constLayout_C);

final ConstraintSet cs_B = new ConstraintSet();
cs_B.connect(constLayout_B.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP);
cs_B.connect(constLayout_B.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, constLayout_C.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
cs_B.connect(constLayout_B.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
cs_B.connect(constLayout_B.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);
cs_B.applyTo(constLayout_B);
```

My `ConstraintSet` is not being applied for some reason. How can I change the top constraint of `constLayout_C` dynamically?

Comment: Have you considered using ConstraintSet for dynamic constraints, and maybe you can attach image of what you have right now, and what you expect it to be?

Comment: I did try ConstraintSet, but not being applied

Comment: Can you show what have you tried with ConstraintSet?

Comment: @ParagPawar question updated

Comment: Okay, so let me know if I understood this correctly. Constraint C is attached to the bottom of A, and now you want to attach C to the bottom of B and Hide A, right?

Comment: Correct. With the example above the result is: square A above square C. I need to programatically change to: square B above square C.

Comment: Okay, first of all, try cloning the constraintset. For example, cs_C.clone(rootView)
Here rootView being your root constraint of all 3 constraints. See if it changes anything

Comment: Also, do this, cs_B.clone(rootView)

Comment: nothing changed. Both views are overlaying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201675/discussion-between-parag-pawar-and-bugdr0id).

Comment: You can try from the answers below, It might solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout B overlays with Layout A because you set broth's  `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` attributes to `parent`.And set constraint layout margin programmatically is not a good practice.
set your layout like this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/constLayout_root"
>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constLayout_A"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="#ff0"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constLayout_B"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:background="#f0f"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constLayout_A" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constLayout_C"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#0f0"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constLayout_B" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And remember the purpose of using constrainLayout is it gives us the facilities to drag and drop the view and set it in Layout,not to consider it to set programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You Constraint B in XML layouts has visibility `Gone`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constLayout_B"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#f0f"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

Change it to `VISIBLE` within XML, or during constrain set changes in code. Make sure you are using `ConstraintSet.clone()` before applying changes.